# How can I add a slide transition effect using javascript with this block of code that already works?

Tags: javascript, html, slider, carousel

First time asking a question here.  I've been serioiusly studying/learning HTML since March of last year and I feel really comfortable with the fundamentals.  Naturally I want to expand upon those fundamentals with Javascript.

I feel like I'm pretty good with studying and taking random lines of codes and backwards engineering them to make something work for me...but not as a super rookie level Javacript beginner.

With that being said, I managed to run across two different lines of Javascript code and merge them together to have a previous and next button, functioning on an infinite loop, with dots to let the person know exactly how many items are hidden.  Basically you click the right arrow and a div disappears and another div takes its place.  You click a dot and it takes you to that particular div as well.  Luckily all that works great, but I want the actual slide effect/transition to show when you click right.  I want the actual slides to move from right to left and vice versa.

I have something called an "Owl Carousel" plugin, that I happened to run across that works pretty good, but I can't (or I'm not knowledgeable enough) to make edits to the existing code to fit what I need, that's why I rather have something a bit from scratch, so I'll know and understand what happens when I make slight changes.

Please, no plugin suggestions or jQuery solutions.  I want to properly understand the fundamentals of Javascript for now.

```css
.ms-content {
 max-width: 100%;
}

.btn-container {
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 10px; 
}

.btn-floating {
 font-size: 42px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;   
}

.btn-floating:hover {
 color: #4FAD52;
}

.dot-two {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #7AC143;
}

.ms-slide-two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.ms-slide-two:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.ms-slide-two:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: #999;
}

.ms-slide-two:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<article class="ms-content">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <a class="btn-floating" onclick="plusDivs_slide_two(-1)">&#10094;</a>     
    <a class="btn-floating" onclick="plusDivs_slide_two(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center; padding-bottom:20px;">
    <span class="dot-two" onclick="currentDivs_slide_two(1)"></span>
   <span class="dot-two" onclick="currentDivs_slide_two(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot-two" onclick="currentDivs_slide_two(3)"></span> 
  </div>
        
  <div class="ms-slide-two">           
    <p>Div One</p>      
  </div>
        
  <div class="ms-slide-two">                     
    <p>Div Two</p>                         
  </div>
  
  <div class="ms-slide-two">                     
    <p>Div Three</p>                         
  </div>
  
        <!-- Manual Slide -->
        <script>
        var slideIndex_slide_two = 1;
  showDivs_slide_two(slideIndex_slide_two);

  function plusDivs_slide_two(n) {
      showDivs_slide_two(slideIndex_slide_two += n);
  }
  
  function currentDivs_slide_two(n) {
      showDivs_slide_two(slideIndex_slide_two = n);
  }

  function showDivs_slide_two(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-slide-two");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot-two");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex_slide_two = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex_slide_two = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    x[slideIndex_slide_two-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex_slide_two-1].className += " active";
  }
  </script>
        <!-- End Manual Slide -->
```